# Lenovo Smart Display returns conv.user.last.seen as undefined

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

When getting conv.user.last.seen, I get a value from Google Assistant on Pixel and from Google Home, but Lenovo Smart Display returns undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Pixel is a personal device and the user storage is all the time available there. A Smart Display and also speakers are **shared devices**. The user storage only works if the **Personal Results** setting inside the Assistant App for that device are turned on.

Important: You never know if you are able to persist data in an Action on Google. You can write data to `conv.user.foo` but never know if it is there if you invoke the action again. So it's important to make sure that the dialogs are well designed even when you were not able to persist data for returning users.

## Update 2019-06-28

Google released a new flag (*yeaah*) to handle this. The flag is called **verification**. You can find the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/guest-users).

Comment: Ahh! Thank you. Didn't realize this was a requirement.